# Under what condition(s) we can use the following relation: $\frac{df(x)}{du}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ the first derivative of function $f(x)$ and we assume that $x=x(u)$ (i.e. depends on $u$). Under what condition(s) we can use the following relation: $\frac{df(x)}{du}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}$.

Comment: both $x(u)$ and $f(x)$ must be differentiable functions

Answer (score 0):

This is called the chain rule its conditions are in your case:

$f$ is differentiable and $x$ has continous first derivative.